# How to call a function within the same controller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

How to call a function within the same controller in Angular 2, because this gives me an error:

```
initialiseWeight(){
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
        return this.storage.get('weightunit');
    })
    .then(retrievedUnit => {
        if (retrievedUnit) {
            this.data.weightunit = retrievedUnit;
        } else {
            this.data.weightunit = 'kg';
            this.storage.set('weightunit', this.data.weightunit);
        }
    })
    .catch(e =>  console.error('ERROR: could not read Storage Weight, error:', e));

    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
        return this.storage.get('realWeight');
    })
    .then(retrievedRealWeight => {
        if (retrievedRealWeight && retrievedRealWeight!== "0" ) {
            this.data.realWeight = parseInt(retrievedRealWeight, 10);
            this.storage.get('userWeight').then((value) => {
                this.data.userWeight = parseInt(value, 10);
              });
             if ( (this.data.realWeight * 1.02 < this.data.userWeight) && (!this.data.isWetsuit) ) {
                this.data.userWeight = this.data.realWeight;
                this.storage.set('userWeight', this.data.userWeight);
            }
        } else {
            this.data.realWeight = 70;
            this.data.userWeight = 70;
            this.storage.set('realWeight', this.data.realWeight);
            this.storage.set('userWeight', this.data.userWeight);
        }
    })
    .catch(e =>  console.error('ERROR: could not read Storage Weight, error:', e));
}
this.initialiseWeight();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the full function? You're probably missing a brace somewhere. Did you mean to call that function recursively by the way?

Comment: Yes I just added the full function. No I don't mean it to call it recursively, it is an initialization function, I want to call it at start only.

Comment: So where do you want to call it from? `ngOnInit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a piece of code within a method so you should call `this.initialiseWeight()` inside another method, for exemple:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initialiseWeight();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call `this.initialiseWeight();` in `ngOnInit()` for initialization purposes or you can call it from another function `someFunction()`

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.initialiseWeight();
}
```

or

```
someFunctionName(){
   this.initialiseWeight();
}
```